# Spring Batch Reader's cursor closed early in JTA transaction managed step

Tags: java, jdbc, spring-batch, jta, xa

The *working* configuration for the step in question is the following:

- Step, Spring Batch Job Repository, and business repositories (using various datasources) all use a JTA transaction manager.
- Step "myStep" uses a Jdbc Paging Item Reader.
- WebLogic, Oracle XE and/or EE

I wanted to analyze the performance of the Jdbc **Cursor** Item Reader in "myStep", however after the first commit, the second chunk's first read would fail with *java.sql.SQLException: Result set already closed*.

I suspected it might be JTA / XA driver closing the cursor for some reason, so I gave "myStep" a simple datasource transaction manager (on the datasource the reader was using), and the step was able to complete successfully. This isn't a solution, since this breaks transactionally integrity of the step.

Should I be able to use a cursor reader inside of a JTA managed step (using the environment described below)? If so, what might be configured incorrectly on my end?

**Environment**

- Transaction Manager:`<bean id="myTransactionManager"
  class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager"/>`
- Datasource Driver: OracleXADataSource JDBC 6 11.1.0.7.0
- WebLogic: 12.1.3.0.0
- Oracle DB 11g: Enterprise Edition 11.2.0.4.0
- OS: OSX or Linux

**Config**

```
<bean id="myTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager"/>

<bean id="myDataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="jdbc/myDataSource"/>
    <property name="proxyInterface" value="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
</bean>

<batch:step id="myStep" job-repository="myJobRepositoryFactory">
    <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="myTransactionManager">
        <batch:chunk
                reader="myReader"
                processor="myProcessor"
                writer="myWriter"
                commit-interval="100"
                processor-transactional="false"/>
        <batch:listeners>
            <batch:listener ref="myListener"/>
        </batch:listeners>
    </batch:tasklet>
</batch:step>

<bean id="myReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader" scope="step">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource"/>
    <property name="sql" value="SELECT * FROM myHugeTable ORDER BY myColumn DESC"/>
    <property name="rowMapper">
        <bean class="myRowMapper"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

**Caught in the act**

Below is the call stack of the result set being closed before the next chunk's read. Notice XA Connection closing all statements, which causes JDBC to close all results sets.

```
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
  at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.ResultSet.internalClose(ResultSet.java:178)
  at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.Statement.closeAllResultSets(Statement.java:286)
  at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.Statement.internalClose(Statement.java:395)
  at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.Statement.internalClose(Statement.java:367)
  at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.XAConnection.closeAllStatements(XAConnection.java:393)
  at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.XAConnection.cleanup(XAConnection.java:406)
  at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.XAConnection.releaseToPool(XAConnection.java:432)
  at weblogic.jdbc.jta.DataSource.removeTxAssoc(DataSource.java:1907)
  at weblogic.jdbc.jta.DataSource.prepare(DataSource.java:1090)
  at weblogic.transaction.internal.XAServerResourceInfo.prepare(XAServerResourceInfo.java:1408)
  at weblogic.transaction.internal.XAServerResourceInfo.prepare(XAServerResourceInfo.java:522)
  at weblogic.transaction.internal.ServerSCInfo.startPrepare(ServerSCInfo.java:411)
  at weblogic.transaction.internal.ServerTransactionImpl.localPrepare(ServerTransactionImpl.java:2709)
  at weblogic.transaction.internal.ServerTransactionImpl.globalPrepare(ServerTransactionImpl.java:2340)
  at weblogic.transaction.internal.ServerTransactionImpl.internalCommit(ServerTransactionImpl.java:300)
  at weblogic.transaction.internal.ServerTransactionImpl.commit(ServerTransactionImpl.java:260)
  at org.glassfish.transaction.TransactionManagerImplCommon.commit(TransactionManagerImplCommon.java:571)
  at org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager.doCommit(JtaTransactionManager.java:1021)
  at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:761)
  at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730)
  at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:150)
  at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:271)
  at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:77)
  at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:368)
  at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
  at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144)
  at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:257)
  at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:198)
  at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148)
  at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:64)
  at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:67)
  at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:165)
  at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:144)
  at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:134)
  at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:304)
  at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:135)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: I don't see your datasource configurations, db driver, weblogic version, operating system etc mentioned anywhere? Could you add the data to the question.

Comment: which threadExecutor are you using?. could you add your job configuration? may helps others too

Comment: @eis I added the info you requested -- let me know if you need more. Thanks for checking this out!

Comment: Could you share code for `Step "myStep" uses a Jdbc Paging Item Reader.`

Comment: @Jan I edited the question with the addition of your requested info. I assume you meant "Jdbc Cursor Item Reader", as I am not trying to use the paging reader.

Comment: Your *Writer* contains a `SELECT` and is setup with `commit-interval=100`... and your system fails within `AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit`...  to me this looks like `SELECT` should be the *Reader* not the *Writer*, because within the *Writer* there will be a commit every 100 inserts to keep commit-set within transaction reasonable small

Comment: @Jan Doh! That was a typo (fixed) from sanitizing names. That bean is really the reader.

Comment: Typo in your question or in your real setup?

Comment: @Jan Typo in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the cursor reader inside a JTA managed step. We are doing exactly this in the project I'm working on. We use Atomikos as XA TM.

Here is our XA/JTA configuration, that we use. Perhaps it is of some use for you:

```
@Bean(initMethod = "init", destroyMethod = "shutdownForce")
public UserTransactionService userTransactionService() {
    return new UserTransactionServiceImp(userTransactionServiceProperties());
}

@Bean(initMethod = "init", destroyMethod = "close")
@DependsOn("userTransactionService")
public UserTransactionManager atomikosTransactionManager() {
    UserTransactionManager userTransactionManager = new UserTransactionManager();
    userTransactionManager.setForceShutdown(true);
    userTransactionManager.setStartupTransactionService(false);
    return userTransactionManager;
}

@Bean
@DependsOn("userTransactionService")
public UserTransaction atomikosUserTransaction() throws SystemException {
    return new UserTransactionImp();
}

@Bean
@DependsOn("userTransactionService")
public JtaTransactionManager transactionManager() throws SystemException {
    JtaTransactionManager jtaTransactionManager = new JtaTransactionManager();
    jtaTransactionManager.setTransactionManager(atomikosTransactionManager());
    jtaTransactionManager.setUserTransaction(atomikosUserTransaction());
    jtaTransactionManager.setAllowCustomIsolationLevels(true);
    return jtaTransactionManager;
}
```

All our datasources are instantiated as org.springframework.boot.jta.atomikos.AtomikosDataSourceBean. E.g., a Ora-datasource is instantiated like this:

```
    AtomikosDataSourceBean oraXaDs = new AtomikosDataSourceBean();
    oraXaDs.setXaDataSourceClassName(oraDsProp.getDatasourceClass());
    oraXaDs.setUniqueResourceName(oraDsProp.getInstancename());
    oraXaDs.setMinPoolSize(oraDsProp.getPoolMinSize());
    oraXaDs.setMaxPoolSize(oraDsProp.getPoolMaxSize());
    oraXaDs.setTestQuery(oraDsProp.getValidConnectionSQL());

    Properties oraXaDsProps = oraXaDs.getXaProperties();
    oraXaDsProps.setProperty("user", oraDsProp.getUser());
    oraXaDsProps.setProperty("password", oraDsProp.getPassword());
    oraXaDsProps.setProperty("URL", oraDsProp.getUrl());
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I think our issue is specific to our WebLogic config; Atomikos is probably handling the cursor differently.

Answer (score 1):

My two cents on this issue:

First some insight :

Reading from a database cursor means opening a connection, firing one SQL statement against it and constantly reading rows during the whole batch job. That makes sense, because often input data of a job can be characterized by one SQL statement, but executing it and reading all the data from the ResultSet upfront is of course no solution. We just have one problem here with reading constantly: committing the transaction would close the connection. **So how do we keep it open? Simple solution: it doesn’t take part in the transaction.** Spring Batch’s JdbcCursorItemReader uses a separate connection for opening the cursor, thereby bypassing the transaction managed by the transaction manager.
In an application server environment we have to do a little bit more to make it work. Normally we get connections from a DataSource managed by the application server, and all of those connections take part in transactions by default. We need to set up a separate DataSource which does not take part in transactions, and only inject it into our cursor based readers. Injecting them anywhere else could cause a lot of damage regarding transaction safety.

Your problem is in your step basically :(from whatever i can conclude without viewing your datasource xml file :) )

**Step, Spring Batch Job Repository, and business repositories (using various datasources) all use a JTA transaction manager.**

The JTA transaction manager spring provides should be used in a way that weblogic handles your JTA transactions instead.What you need is only configure the datasource (which should be also under the container) to use XA-aware drivers, and in your app, use the corresponding transaction manager, and lookup the XA-aware datasources by JNDI

However if you cannot rely on the container (e.g. you are writing a standalone app, and etc), you will need to find an transaction manager that is capable on that. Atomikos is one the the most famous free JTA/XA library.

Having said that,after you have configured with either the JNDI way or Atomikos way,here are the configuration which should be kept in mind while using multiple datasources:

```
<batch:tasklet>
  <batch:transaction-attributes isolation="READ_COMMITTED" propagation="REQUIRES_NEW" timeout="200"/>
  <batch:chunk reader="myItemReader" writer="myItemWriter" commit-interval="20"/>
</batch:tasklet>
```

Hope this clears out some air on this issue.

Comment: The first segment of your comment is from @Tobias Flohre 's blog: https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2012/03/transactions-in-spring-batch-part-2-restart-cursor-based-reading-and-listeners/

Comment: If I take Tobias' advice and create an extra datasource with a non-XA driver, and use this extra datasource with the cursor, everything works. My question remains though: Can we keep a cursor open, across commits, using an XA datasource, within a JTA transaction?
--
To your later points: The datasource is configured using JNDI, is configured to use XA drivers, and we experience this issue of the cursor's result set being closed after a commit.